# split string multiple times with one delimiter and extract right side with php

Tags: php, split, explode

The string im working with is similar to @add foo @add foo2 @add foo3.
how can i split the string into multiple parts and extract everything to the right of each '@add'.

Answer (score 1):

```
explode('@add',$string); //generates an array of these values
```

ignore the first value of the array, rest of the elements is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

All the values except zero index will return you the right result.

```
$str = '@add foo @add foo2 @add foo3';
$arr = explode('@add',$str);

echo $arr[1]."<br/>";
echo $arr[2]."<br/>";
echo $arr[3]."<br/>";
```